# Youtube Data API C# - use without requesting user credentials

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I would like to use the YouTubeData API in C# - .Net Core - without requesting user credentials.
The only thing I need from this API is to retrieve the information of a playlist, but always when I use it on localhost it is requesting the user's credential.
How can I use this API without any request for credential or using my own token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve information (title, thumbnail) of a public playlist, you only need an API key. You only need to authenticate the user if you want to create or edit playlists.

This sample program retrieves the title and the thumbnail of a playlist by id.

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;

namespace YtbExample
{
    internal class PlayList
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                new PlayList().Run().Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private async Task Run()
        {
            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY",
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });

            var listRequest = youtubeService.Playlists.List("snippet");
            listRequest.Id = "PLdo4fOcmZ0oXzJ3FC-ApBes-0klFN9kr9";
            //Get playlists by channel id
            //listRequest.ChannelId = "";

            listRequest.MaxResults = 50;


            var listResponse = await listRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            List<string> playlists = new List<string>();

            // Add each result to the list, and then display the lists of
            // matching playlists.
            foreach (var result in listResponse.Items)
            {
                playlists.Add(String.Format("Title: {0}, Id: {1}, Thumbnail: {2}", result.Snippet.Title, result.Id, result.Snippet.Thumbnails.Medium.Url));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}\n", string.Join("\n", playlists)));
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I could help you!